# How to find object by id from vue-router params and then pass it's properties to template in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am getting data from vuex state in my ContactDetails component, then storing it in contacts array, and after that I am under computed trying to find and return object based on id props passed from router params.

This is the code

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      contacts: [],
    };
  }, 
  props: ["id"],

  created() {
    this.contacts = this.$store.getters.getContacts;
  },
  computed:{
    contact () {
      return this.contacts.find(contact => {
        contact.id === this.id
      })
    }
  }
```

but somehow I keep getting that object undefined:
[image]

Comment: Can you create a codepen or jsfiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: can I help with github repo https://github.com/MarkoCvrljak/vue-contact-book-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. Type mismatch. Contact.id is of type number, but url prop id is a string.
2. When using find, you should either use arrow function which has implicit return (recommended) or you can use curly braces but have to use return keyword.

```
 contact() {
      return this.contacts.find(contact => contact.id === parseInt(this.id));
    }
```